# NSData to NSArray of NSNumbers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm coming from Swift to Objective-C and a problem I have run into is that NSData doesn't seem have methods to enumerate over UInt8 values the way Swift's Data does. Other answers with similar titles exist but they all deal with property lists, whereas I just have a bucket of ASCII bytes. Specifically, the code I want to replicate in Obj-C is:

```
//Find the next newline in ASCII data given a byte offset
let subset = myData.advanced(by: offset)
var lineEnd: Data.Index = myData.endIndex

subset.enumerateBytes({ (memory, idx, stop) in
    let newline: UInt8 = 10

    for idx in memory.indices {
        let charByte = memory[idx]

        if charByte == newline {
            lineEnd = idx
            stop = true; return;
        }
    }
})
```

Ideally I want a way to convert an NSArray to an array of NSNumbers which I can extract the intValues from. Of course, if there is a better method, let me know. A goal is to keep the Obj-C code as similar to Swift as possible as I will be maintaining the two codebases simultaneously.

Comment: Why maintain both Swift and Objective-C? Put the Objective-C into maintenance mode and bridge over new Swift code to cover the stuff you replace. Maintaining two codebases for no good reason is simply duplication of work and a source of errors.

Comment: I originally wrote the app in Swift but it turned out to be 4 MB over the App Store binary hosting limit. All the resources in the app are ASCII text I really couldn't remove, so the Swift runtime was the only thing that can be cut. So I'm rewriting the app in Obj-C. When the Swift ABI stabilizes I will swap the codebases out. Yes, I'm aware of the absurdity of this situation.

Comment: @PopKernel could remote downloading some of the extra resources when the user installs the app be a solution to avoid recoding everything? :)

Comment: Introduces a lot of complexity considering the codebase is about 200 lines large. A rewrite would be faster and more performant.

Comment: Yes, the Swift ABI situation is a pain but it seems like there must be some other alternative. Have you tried [Technical Q&A QA1795](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html)? Isn't the binary limit something like 8GB now?

Comment: It's an Apple Watch app. Binary limit is 50 MB.

Comment: Ahh. Hmm, why not store the data in the iOS app and transfer it later to keep the binary smaller? [Sharing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html) - I feel like you're doing a lot of extra work that could be avoided.

Comment: Definitely a possible solution, but again given the core of the app is 200 loc long it introduces a lot of complexity because I can't just throw up a progress bar. I'd have to schedule it in the background, and account for what happens if the phone loses connection, consider whether I should be just pulling files from a server instead, etc.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely something to work around. My Obj-C is rusty or I'd give a crack at this. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only good way to access an `NSData`'s bytes is to call its `-bytes` method, which gets you a C pointer to its internal storage.

```
NSData *data = ...;
const uint8_t *bytes = data.bytes;
NSUInteger length = data.length;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    uint8_t byte = bytes[i];

    // do something with byte
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that method but the signature was const * void which confused me. This example is helpful!!

Comment: The `const * void` is just there because the data referred to by the `NSData` object can technically be any type, not just bytes. It could, for example, be an array of `uint32_t`s. You just cast it to whatever the correct type is, which in this case is bytes. Of course, if you're doing something fancy, you need to pay attention to alignment issues as well.

Comment: One other thing I should mention: Since the `bytes` pointer points to the `NSData`'s internal storage, don't hang onto it longer than you hang onto the `NSData`. If you try to use the `bytes` pointer after the `NSData` object has been deallocated... well... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ls5j5iz2eA

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent to `advance` would be `subdataWithRange`. The equivalent to `enumerateBytes` is `enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock`. It would yield something like:

```
NSData *subset = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(offset, data.length - offset)];
__block NSUInteger lineEnd = data.length;

Byte newline = 10;

[subset enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:^(const void * _Nonnull bytes, NSRange byteRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < byteRange.length; index++) {
        Byte charByte = ((Byte *)bytes)[index];
        
        if (charByte == newline) {
            lineEnd = index + byteRange.location;
            *stop = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}];
```

Note, I made a few changes from your Swift example:

1. If the data was not contiguous, your Swift example returns the index within the current block. But I suspect you want the location within `subset`, not the current block. I'm wagering that you've never noticed this because it's pretty rare that `NSData` blocks are not continuous.

   But the Swift code doesn't look correct to me. This Objective-C example reports the offset within `subset`, not within the current block within `subset`.
2. It's not observable performance difference, but I pulled the definition of `newline` out of the enumeration block. Why repeatedly define that?
3. If you're really searching for a character in the `NSData`, I'd suggest avoiding creating the `subset` altogether. Just use [`rangeOfData:options:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410391-rangeofdata?language=objc). This will find whatever you're looking for.

Comment: Nice catch on the myData thing. I'll look at your answer in more detail tomorrow, I shouldn't be up this late as it is! ⌛️